# How to create a bulk operation transactions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The below function is working fine however If any record contain non UTF-8 character, it gives 500 error.

Can I use transaction here for bulk operation so that either all records are saved or none of them does?

I have try with various encoding fix issue as mentioned on stackoverflow but that doesn't work.

```
def convert_save(model_name, csv_data, field_name=nil)
      target_model = model_name.classify.constantize
      csv_file = csv_data.read
      row_headers={}
      counter=0;
      all_recs=[];
      #Thread.new do
                CSV.parse(csv_file) do |row| 
                    if counter==0
                        temp=row
                        row_headers = Hash[temp.map.with_index.to_a]
                        counter +=1
                        next
                    end
                        #start fetch row and put into active record object
                        unless row[row_headers["name"]].nil?
                            temp={}
                            temp_time={}
                            for name in [:business_type_id, :user_id, :name, :country_id, :latitude, :longitude, :free_shipping]
                                temp[name] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]]
                            end
                            for name in [:homepage, :telephone, :email, :address, :facebook, :twitter, :google, :instagram, :pinterest, :ship_details]
                                temp[name] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]] ||= ""
                            end
                            for name in [:category_ids, :style_ids, :filter_ids, :shipping_country_ids]
                                temp[name] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]].try(:split, ",") unless row_headers[name.to_s].nil?
                            end
                            for name in [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday, :public_holiday]
                                temp_time[name.to_s] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]]  ||= ""
                            end
                            temp_time["appointment_only"] = row[row_headers["appointment_only"]]
                            temp["business_timing_attributes"] = temp_time
                            all_recs.push(temp)
                        end 
                end
                Business.create(all_recs)
                ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
      end
    #end
  end
```

Comment: It seems like you're asking about transactions as well as an encoding issue. You should try to ask one question at a time.

Comment: The main motive of transaction is to avoid encode error. If any issue come due to encode the partial record save so that create an issue. I did not find any better solution for encoding till now.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you're getting encoding errors and other SO questions haven't helped you solve them you should post a question describing the problem, including the exact error messages you're getting.

Comment: Definitely, sometimes we need the alternate solution until we have optimized one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your `create` method in a transaction. If any INSERT fails, the whole operation will be rolled back:

```
Business.transaction do
  Business.create!(all_recs)
end
```

Note that in order for a transaction to be rolled back an ActiveRecord error has to occur as a result of the query. Thus, you'll have to use `create!` instead of `create` here to ensure an exception is thrown for invalid data.

Comment: `create` will run, but it won't rollback INSERTS for all users since the query within `transaction` began running.